# insert url into address bar

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have been looking at combining the following two ideas as I need to go to a relative URL based on the current URL

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_hostname from which I have:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = location.hostname;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= x;
    }
</script>
```

And then:

```
var newUrl = "";
window.location = newUrl/x;
```

So that I can have a button on the page to take me from domain1.suffix

to `domain2.suffix/domain2.suffix` for a page concerning that domain

Can anyone help me piece this together?

Comment: Is it just the string concatenation you need help with? `window.location = newUrl + '/' + x;`. Simply using `/` will try to perform a division of the two variables.

Comment: Using concat(), you can combine strings

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function GetHost()
        {
            var protocol = "http://";
            var x = location.hostname;
            window.open((protocol + x));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerText = protocol + x;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Test It" onclick="GetHost()" />
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work nicely - many thanks. I also liked the concat() and newUrl + '/' + x comments! Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openWin() {
                var x = "http://" + location.hostname;
                window.open(x);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="openWin()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```